# Installing developer gmail add-on on G Suite account

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I'm trying to install a developer Gmail add-on on my G Suite account (the email address does not end in "gmail.com"). The add-on was developed and tested using a gmail.com account.
However, when I insert the development ID into the "Developer add-ons" field and click install, instead of the name of the add-on I'm getting this error message:

```
This developer add-on is restricted by policies within your organization.
```

What policies could restrict a gmail add-on and how do I change them (...or the add-on to adhere to the policies)?

Comment: Contact your  organization's technical support.

Comment: If you are an admin for the domain you should be able to change those settings from the admin console for your GSuite domain.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Admin > Marketplace Apps > Google Script and set ALLOW for you or whichever users you want to install.

Comment: Where do I find the Admin section? I tried https://script.google.com/, https://console.developers.google.com/, the script editor and my G Drive, but it isn't anywhere there.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an unpublished addon, it must have been created by a developer from the same domain (i.e. has an @your-domain.com GSuite email address). If it does not, duplicate the appscript file so you own it, and try adding it then.

Relevant part of the [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/install-unpublished): `Users in a G Suite organization can only install and run unpublished add-ons authored by users in the same organization.`